# Removing whitespace and newlines in txt file with python

Tags: python, newline, data-cleaning

I managed to replace the things i wanted with a `;`  but now i struggle to remove the whitespace and newlines to get all the data until `;` on a single line and then start the next.

Code:

```
replacements = {'Geboren am':';', 'Nato/a il':';', 'Né(e) le':';'}

with open('DATEN2.txt') as infile, open('DATENBEARBEITET2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
for line in infile:
    for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
        line = line.replace(src, target)
outfile.write(line)
```

What the input file looks like: (after the replacement)

```
       Kommissionen und Delegationen




                        06.12.1999 - 30.11.2003 




                    Begnadigungskommission (BeK-V)     



               ;
```

What it should look like:

```
Kommissionen und Delegationen, 06.12.1999 - 30.11.2003, Begnadigungskommission (BeK-V);
```

After a long time of searching I came to ask here if someone knows the correct repository or command to use for this kind of task, i'm really struggling to go to the next step.

Edit:/ Also, what was newlines before should turn into a comma, see sample output

Comment: what does the input file looks like?

Comment: edited my post to make it clear, the information with a lot of whitespace and empty lines is the input file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to eliminate the *extra* whitespace - eliminating all of it would result in `KommissionenundDelegationen,06...`. You can do that with `strip()` and `join()`:

```
replacements = {'Geboren am':';', 'Nato/a il':';', 'Né(e) le':';'}

lines = []
with open('DATEN2.txt') as infile, open('DATENBEARBEITET2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
            line = line.replace(src, target)
        lines.append(line)
    outfile.write(', '.join(lines))
```

This creates a `list` consisting of lines that have more than whitespace, with each line stripped of whitespace and with the appropriate replacements made. The `list` is then joined with a delimiter of `', '`.